# java looping using a Yes or No option Pane

Tags: java, loops

my objective is to read from the keyboard a description of an expense and then an actual expense and then ask YES or NO and if YES it loops back to ask for another expense description and expense all whilst adding the number of expenses and the total the user input. I know what to do if the option is no i am just having trouble looping the yes option back to start

heres what i have so far

```
public static double budgetAmount;
public static int totalExpenses;
public static String expenseDescription;
public static int expense;
public static boolean proceed;
public static String value;
public static double runningTotal;
public static int answer;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String bdgtAmnt1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Budget Amount:");
    budgetAmount = Double.parseDouble(bdgtAmnt1);
    do {  

    expenseDescription = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the description of the Expense in 32 letters");
    String expense1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Expense Amount:");
    budgetAmount = Double.parseDouble(expense1);
    if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) runningTotal += expense;
    totalExpenses++;

    answer =  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are there any more items to be entered?", "End Expense Report", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        System.exit(0);
    else if (answer == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        System.out.println("One more time");

    } while(answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
}
```

Comment: Have you ever looked at your code and thought what you're doing there? If first check if the `answer` is yes and in that case kill the whole process. And later you check that again to perform a loop? Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Why are you doing a System.exit(0); if the answer if Yes. I thought you want to keep looping that case.

Comment: well yes i know it exits if i click yes lol i don't know how to loop it back to the top...hence why I'm here. If ur so smart maybe you can tell me how i can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic looks inverted: if I press yes, then I should keep putting more items in the list...
So change this:

```
if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    System.exit(0);
else if (answer == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
    System.out.println("One more time");
```

for:

```
if (answer == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
    System.exit(0);
else if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    System.out.println("One more time");
```

Comment: OHHHHHHH wait so System.out.println("One more time "); does that have to be there? whats its purpose?